# html5 or xml which UI pattern should I adopt to build my android app?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am designing an android application for which I want to use web view (html) for the whole UI part though it is not completely dependent on web. Is there any harm if I don't use xml buttons, textviews etc.

As I am more comfortable in html5 , so do I need to learn xml UI of android or carry forward using html5 approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there is no Harm if you just load your HTML or website inside the WebView (through the complete app).

> Android has always been about connectivity and providing a great web
>   browsing experience, so building your app with web technologies can be
>   a great opportunity. Not only can you build an app on the web and
>   still optimize your designs for Android's various screen sizes and
>   densities, but you can also embed web-based content into your Android
>   app using WebView.

Read more [**Web Apps**](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html).

> If you want to deliver a web application (or just a web page) as a
>   part of a client application, you can do it using WebView.

Read more [**Building Web Apps in WebView**](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

And i would suggest you to check this document: [**Best Practices for Web Apps**](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/best-practices.html)

Comment: Would the control over the widgets on the html page like <Buttons,Textbox etc.> be seamless with the android Java code.